# Cumulative Sum with Reset BEFORE Negative in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

Can someone help me with calculating the cumulative sum of these values where the cumulative is/resets to 0 before it reaches a negative number. I'm trying to implement this using pyspark

df =

+-----+

|value|

+-----+

|   -1|
|    3|
|   -2|
|    2|
|   -1|
+-----+

expected result :
+-----+-------+

|value|cum_sum|

+-----+-------+

|   -1|      0|

|    3|      3|

|   -2|      1|

|    2|      3|

|   -1|      2|

+-----+-------+

Answer (score 2):

For Spark>=2.4.0, you can first apply [`collect_list`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list.html?highlight=collect_list) to collect preeceding `value` as a list and then use [`aggregate`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#aggregate) to find the cumulative sum.

> I am defining an ordering column for use with the Window function, it's advised to have this as spark does not guarantee ordering.

> I don't define a partition in my code when using over a large number of rows, partition the dataset appropriately.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

data = [(1, -1), (2, 3), (3, -2), (4, 2), (5, -1)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("ordering_column", "value"))

ws = W.orderBy("ordering_column").rowsBetween(W.unboundedPreceding, W.currentRow)

cum_sum_expr = F.expr("aggregate(cum_sum_values, 0L, (acc, x) -> greatest(acc + x, 0L))")

(df.withColumn("cum_sum_values", F.collect_list("value").over(ws))
  .withColumn("cum_sum", cum_sum_expr)
  .drop("cum_sum_values")
  .show())

"""
+---------------+-----+-------+
|ordering_column|value|cum_sum|
+---------------+-----+-------+
|              1|   -1|      0|
|              2|    3|      3|
|              3|   -2|      1|
|              4|    2|      3|
|              5|   -1|      2|
+---------------+-----+-------+
"""
```

Comment: seems WindowSpec is missing here

Comment: @Suresh Thanks for pointing out the miss, I have added it now.